# How to simulate middle-click

Tags: mouse

You can simulate a right mouse-click with the magic mouse if you tap the right half of the mouse without touching the left half and THEN click.

But is it possible to achieve a middle-mouse-click with the magic mouse (on OSX 10.6)?

And How?

Comment: Feel free to edit this if the duplicate question is materially different than what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

### [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net)

With BetterTouchTool, you can create a Magic Mouse action to middle-click, such as this:

[image: Magic Mouse Gesture: Single Finger Middle Click → Predefined Action: Middleclick]

---

*For trackpad users*, BTT gives you the option to perform a 'special' middle click designed for CAD users (accessible through **Advanced** → **Action Settings** → **Settings for Predefined Actions** → **Use special middle click mode**).

> This allows people who work with CAD software etc. to perform a real middleclick using the trackpad. Use predefined action middleclick in combination with "three finger click" gesture. Click with 3 fingers then release two of them and move the remaining finger to drag the view around.

Comment: Thanks for this (3 years later)!!  Just rebuilt my MBP, and couldn't get my middle click to work.  But I don't remember having done this in BTT before I rebuilt, but it's been so long that I must have just forgotten that I ever did it.

Answer (score 1):

With [MagigPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) you can change the setting so the middle area of the mouse does create a middleclick as expected.